# MOSFET switching seeing unneccessary pulse during Power ON

Tags: powermosfet

We have a MOSFET switching circuit to switch secondary(battery 5V) supply to load if power lost on primary(12V).

Circuit works fine currently.

But i am seeing a LOW pulse on highlighted red net in the attached capture **ONLY during Power UP**.

[image]

Input to MOSFET from CPLD is LOW.

Power net Vbat1(drain resister voltage) is rising smoothly.

this looks hypothetical to me. Because for a n-Channel MOSFET switch gate is 0V, still looks like MOSFET is ON for short time.

Is there any way pulse**(Low spike)** is generated on highlighted red net even though gate is @ 0V.

I will add few captures tomorrow.

One of the capture:
[image]

Zoomed up
[image]

Comment: What is the length of the highlighted red net on the PCB/wired setup? If it is long, it may pick up noise and 10k might be too low to beat that noise.

Comment: BTW, could you please confirm (or disconfirm) the net "Vbatt1" is different from the net "Battery"?

Comment: Which way is the power flowing here? How do I reference one of the MOSFETs if they are not labeled?

Comment: @Huisman: Vbat1 is diode OR'ed of Switched Rail and Battery voltage.

Comment: @rdtsc: Whole board is powered by Switched Rail. Default power flow will be From Primary rail to Switched Rail, When Primary power lost we see this circuit and its auxillary circuits make sure Secondary power source(Vbat) connects to Switched Rail.

Comment: You need to unambiguously explain what the different colour traces on the oscilloscope picture are and relate those nodes to the circuit diagram.

Comment: @Andy aka: I also deleted that explanation. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Would you mind addressing my first comment, as well as confirming the resistor value of 10k (in your drawing as well as in reality (double-check!))? Still, I suspect the NMOS being triggered rather than noise coupled into the "highlighted red net". According the "Zoomed up" scope image, blue trace, the NMOS is turned on for something like 500ns. Next, the RC-charge shaped curve must be the right most PMOS being charged up by net "Vbatt1" though the 10k resistor.

Comment: **So**, could you please remeasure "Aux loss1", placing the probe+ground as closest to the NMOS, with NO attenuation, scope on 100mV/DIV? (Regarding addressing "the NMOS" and "right most PMOS": please, use [reference designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) when drawing schematics!)

Comment: @Huisman: I believe same, unfortunately i need to move another high priority issue. this kept in hold currently. I will updated as and when i complete the testing. Thanks for the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

A CPLD in reset mode may have leakage resistance and capacitance to Vdd if undefined as an input.  This can be shunted with a 1k resistor or higher or some capacitance to 0V (>1nF) to CLPD output.

Alternatively the PFET gate can have some capacitance added from Vbat source to Gate but that depends on duration and RdsOn*C of NFET.

However I do not see any low voltage detect circuit to properly control this.